# How to push divs vertically?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I have
[image: Here is what I have]

And here is what I want to accomplish

[image: Here is what I want]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .card{
                background-color: aqua;
                border-radius: 10px;
                width: 30%;
                margin: 1% 1%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:200px;" class="card">1</div>
        <div style="height:240px;" class="card">2</div>
        <div style="height:200px;" class="card">3</div>
        <div style="height:270px;" class="card">4</div>
        <div style="height:300px;" class="card">5</div>
        <div style="height:250px;" class="card">6</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping them in inline-block divs? https://jsfiddle.net/ddoticus/6zh8gt35/

Comment: You can use masonry js plugins for doing that....within css not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try like this-

Just use this below script -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

```css
.card{
  background-color: aqua;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1% 1%;
  display:inline-flex;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class=" grid js-masonry">
          <div style="height:200px;" class="card grid-item">1</div>
          <div style="height:240px;" class="card grid-item">2</div>
          <div style="height:200px;" class="card grid-item">3</div>
          <div style="height:270px;" class="card grid-item">4</div>
          <div style="height:300px;" class="card grid-item">5</div>
          <div style="height:250px;" class="card grid-item">6</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

import bootstrap and format the divs using col-md- in rows. i believe you have that css.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .card{
                background-color: aqua;
                border-radius: 10px;
                width: 30%;
                margin: 1% 1%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="rows">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div style="height:200px;" class="card">1</div>
        <div style="height:240px;" class="card">2</div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div style="height:200px;" class="card">3</div>
        <div style="height:270px;" class="card">4</div></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div style="height:300px;" class="card">5</div>
        <div style="height:250px;" class="card">6</div></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible using plain CSS.

You can either change your HTML to have a wrapping "column" div for every two (in your case) `.card` elements, or alternatively there are lots of javascript plugins that you can easily achieve this layout by manipulating the HTML dynamically... Check http://masonry.desandro.com/ as one good example

Answer (score -1):

This is the quick answer; but for DIVs with dynamic heights, I beleive it's better using a jQuery plugin (e.g. masonary as Ronen mentioned).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .card{
                background-color: aqua;
                border-radius: 10px;
                width: 30%;
                margin: 1% 1%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:200px;" class="card">1</div>
        <div style="height:240px;" class="card">2</div>
        <div style="height:200px;" class="card">3</div>
        <div style="height:270px; top:-40px; position:relative;" class="card">4</div>
        <div style="height:300px;" class="card">5</div>
        <div style="height:250px;  top:-40px; position:relative;" class="card">6</div>
    </body>
</html>
```